# Detect if a form POST browser window is open in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, window

I have a form post method, which is used to show a new page.  Its done this way so that the arguments used cannot be seen in the location bar.

Each window is given a unique name, but I want to be able to detect if this browser window is already open, so that calling this form again will not force that current browser window to auto-fresh.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're opening new windows in Javascript.  So, assign a variable name to your new window (e.g. `var newWin1 = window.open(...)`)

Then test to see if the document of your window exists:

```
if(newWin1.document) { alert("Window is open!"); }
else { alert("Window is gone!"); }
```

For a security note: people can still see the `post` data you're sending with any HTTP header tool.  Check out LiveHTTPHeaders for Firefox (or a million others) to see what I mean.

Another note: Not sure what you're doing, but people don't like when a webpage does things without them asking it to (like opening windows).  You may want to consider improving your design to a more user-friendly method.